# Flex wrap hover CSS issues. Hover making .li go wild

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Have a flex list which I've manged to get on a 4x4 row, as I have a total of 16 locations to add.

https://codepen.io/SteveGWR/pen/NaZJyp

```
<div class="container">

    <ul class="grid-list">
      <li class="bath">
        <div class="destination-title">Bath</div>
        <div class="destination-copy"><span>Bath ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></div>
      </li>

      <li class="bristol">
        <div class="destination-title">Bristol</div>
        <div class="destination-copy"><span>Bristol ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></div>
      </li>

      <li class="cardiff">
        <div class="destination-title">Cardiff</div>
        <div class="destination-copy"><span>Cardiff ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></div>
      </li>

      <li class="cornwall">
        <div class="destination-title">Cornwall</div>
        <div class="destination-copy"><span>Cornwall ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></div>
      </li>


      <li class="dorset">
        <div class="destination-title">Dorset</div>
        <div class="destination-copy"><span>Dorset ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></div>
      </li>



      <li class="Cotswolds">
        <div class="destination-title">Cotswolds</div>
        <div class="destination-copy"><span>Cotswolds ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></div>
      </li>

      <li class="Exeter">
        <div class="destination-title">Exeter</div>
        <div class="destination-copy"><span>Exeter ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></div>
      </li>


      <li class="London">
        <div class="destination-title">London</div>
        <div class="destination-copy"><span>London ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></div>
      </li>


    </ul>

    </div>
```

Problem is when you hover it goes wild.

Anything i'm missing in the CSS to solve this?

Comment: Its behaving the way you have assigned it to behave on hover. Can you please explain what you meant by "goes wild" and what your expected hover result should be.

Comment: What I mean is,  Im trying to figure out how to get a smoother transition. I think what is happening right now is that it thinks it has no extra space to push the other .li into position.  flex-wrap: wrap; has something to do with it. Better example : https://codepen.io/guerresinge/pen/qPezML

Comment: @Steve to clarify, you don't like that hvering over a single element shrinks the other elements to make room?

Comment: @DavidMillar I do like the function of the hover on single element > enlarge > shrink other elements. But In my example its very choppy and not fluid. Try hovering over "Cornwall" you'll see what I mean

Comment: It actualy work realy fine on firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is the `flex-wrap: wrap` that makes them go wild, group them 4 by 4 and remove wrapping.

I also added a `z-index` so the hovered item stays on top.

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jaExxm)

Stack snippet

```css
* {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.container {
 
 position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -475px;
    background: #FF4346;
        max-width: 950px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 10px;
    height: 748px;
 
 
}

.grid-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    height: 230px;
}

.col {
  flex: 1;
}


.grid-list .col {
  width: 32%;
}

.grid-list li {
  position:relative;
  height:100%;

}

.destination-copy {
  display:none;
  opacity:0;
  transition:1s all;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  width:100%;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  color:#fff;
  padding:12px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: arial;
}

.grid-list li:hover .destination-copy {
  animation: 1s ease 0s normal forwards 1 fadein;
  display:block;
}

@keyframes fadein{
    0% { opacity:0; }
    66% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}

.grid-list li {
    transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    width: 25%; /*CHANGE*/
 
    /* min-width: 237px; */
    /* margin: 1em; */
    /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
    list-style: none;
}

.grid-list li:hover {
  width:200%;
  height:150%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.destination-title {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:80px;
  right:0px;
  background-color:#054940;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:16px;
  padding:6px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Background images */
.bath {
  background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/600/350);  
}
.bath:hover {
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/600/350);
}

.bristol {
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/600/355);
}
.bristol:hover {
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/600/355);
}

.cardiff {
  background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/600/356);
}
.cardiff:hover {
  background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/600/356);
}

.cornwall {
  background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/600/357);
 clear: right;
}
.cornwall:hover {
  background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/600/357);
}

.dorset {
  background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/600/359);
 clear: left;
}
.dorset:hover {
  background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/600/359);
}


.Cotswolds {
  background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/600/365);
 clear: left;
}
.Cotswolds:hover {
  background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/600/365);
}


.Exeter {
  background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/600/366);
 clear: left;
}
.Exeter:hover {
  background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/600/366);
}


.London {
  background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/600/367);
 clear: left;
}
.London:hover {
  background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/600/367);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<ul class="grid-list">
  <li class="bath">
    <div class="destination-title">Bath</div>
    <div class="destination-copy"><span>Bath ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></div>
  </li>
  
  <li class="bristol">
    <div class="destination-title">Bristol</div>
    <div class="destination-copy"><span>Bristol ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></div>
  </li>
  
  <li class="cardiff">
    <div class="destination-title">Cardiff</div>
    <div class="destination-copy"><span>Cardiff ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></div>
  </li>
  
  <li class="cornwall">
    <div class="destination-title">Cornwall</div>
    <div class="destination-copy"><span>Cornwall ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></div>
  </li>
</ul>  

<ul class="grid-list">
  <li class="dorset">
    <div class="destination-title">Dorset</div>
    <div class="destination-copy"><span>Dorset ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></div>
  </li>
  
  
  
  <li class="Cotswolds">
    <div class="destination-title">Cotswolds</div>
    <div class="destination-copy"><span>Cotswolds ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></div>
  </li>
  
  <li class="Exeter">
    <div class="destination-title">Exeter</div>
    <div class="destination-copy"><span>Exeter ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></div>
  </li>
  
  
  <li class="London">
    <div class="destination-title">London</div>
    <div class="destination-copy"><span>London ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></div>
  </li>  
  
</ul>

</div>
```

---

Updated based on a comment, where the row below won't be pushed down when resize the image.

By moving the `height: 190px` from `.grid-list` to `.grid-list li`, and then change the `.grid-list li:hover` to `height: 270px;` (150% of 190px), the row below will move down

*Note, the codepen here is somewhat updated compared to the original.*

[Updated codepen 2](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bYVRyz?editors=1100)

Comment: Yes!! This is what I was trying to achieve thanks. On hover, Is there anyway to push the below 4 elements without over-lapping?

Comment: @Steve Will have a look in a while.

Comment: @Steve I did gave it a quick look yesterday, though didn't find a fix for that, and am to busy now, so if you need quicker help, post that part as a new question.

Comment: @Steve Updated my answer with a 2nd codepen, where the elements below will be pushed down instead of overlap on hover (so now you can delete the newer question :) ... Note, I used the codepen from your latest question for this update

Comment: Aha!! Beautiful. Thanks very much. Very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `scale` instead of changing the width. This will not affect the other elements. Make the CSS of `.grid-list li:hover` like this :

```
.grid-list li:hover {
    position:relative;
    transform: scaleX(1.5);
    max-width: 380px;
    height: 150%;
    z-index: 99;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: scale is a nice effect. But it overlaps with the z-indexing instead of pushing the other elements

Comment: @Steve yes right, this is not what you want ? this is what i understand

Comment: Do not want scaling. 

Want this: https://codepen.io/guerresinge/pen/qPezML

But My code is doing this: https://codepen.io/SteveGWR/pen/NaZJyp